# How do I load a QGIS SLD into Openlayers Vector Layer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, node-modules, openlayers

I am attempting to load an SLD into the newest version of openlayers and it appears they no longer have an internal library for SLD.  I have been searching the internet and all I have been able to find is using GeoStyler to handle the conversion. Below is a very simple example of what I have tried.

```
<script>
import OpenLayersParser from "geostyler-openlayers-parser";
import SLDParser from "geostyler-sld-parser";
export default {
  async mounted() {
    const sldParser = new SLDParser();
    const olParser = new OpenLayersParser();
    try{
      const { output: geostylerStyle } = await sldParser.readStyle(self.SLDFile);
      console.log('GEOSTYLER STYLE',geostylerStyle);
      const { output: olStyle } = await olParser.writeStyle(geostylerStyle);
      console.log('STYLE',olStyle);
    }catch(error){ 
      console.error('STYLER ERROR',error); 
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      "SLDFile": `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor 
mlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld 
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" 
xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se"
>
<NamedLayer>
  <se:Name>county_boundaries</se:Name>
  <UserStyle>
  <se:Name>county_boundaries</se:Name>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
    <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
    <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
      <se:Fill>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#8d5a99</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Fill>
      <se:Stroke>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff0101</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Stroke>
    </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The output is missing all the style details for the above example the output from geostylerStyle is the following:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Single symbol",
        "symbolizers": [
            {
                "kind": "Fill"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The issue with that is it is not processing my sld file to include the fill, fill-opacity,stroke and so on.  Has anyone else run into issues with this plugin or have any other ideas to create this conversion.